# How to see if an object is an instanceof a class that extends a particular parent in java

Tags: java, oop

I want to be able to check for whether an object is an instanceof a class that extends a particular parent class. Below is the relevant portion of code I'm writing. I want to set the aggType variable based on aggDef being of a particular child type. I know I can't do the following as shown below in the code, but is there a technique I can follow to do this kind of functionality? **Unfortunately, proper object oriented design is not an option where I can define an abstract method in the parent and have the children know what type they are as these are proprietary inaccessible internal libraries**

```
    String aggType=null;
    AggDef aggDef = queryAggs.get(aggsKey);
        if(aggDef != null){
           if(aggDef instanceof TermAggDef){
                    aggType = "terms";
                } 
                else if (aggDef instanceof ? extends StatAggDef){
                    aggType = "terms_stats";
                }
                else if (aggDef instanceof RangeAggDef){
                    aggType = "range";
                } else{
                    aggType= "statistical";
                }
            }
     }
```

The alternative would be the way I have it below which does compile and work. But it's tedious and really ugly. How can this be improved?

```
String aggType;
AggDef aggDef = queryAggs.get(aggsKey);
if(aggDef != null){

    if(aggDef instanceof TermAggDef){
        aggType = "terms";
    } 
    else if (aggDef instanceof StatAggDef){
        if(aggDef instanceof AvgAggDef){
            aggType= "statistical";
        }else if(aggDef instanceof MaxAggDef){
            aggType= "statistical";
        }else if(aggDef instanceof MinAggDef){
            aggType= "statistical";
        }else if(aggDef instanceof SumAggDef){
            aggType= "statistical";
        } else{
            aggType = "terms_stats";
        }
    }
    else if (aggDef instanceof RangeAggDef){
        aggType = "range";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make yourself a `Map<Class<? extends AggDef>, String>`; populate it; and look it up via `aggDef.getClass()` instead of the if-else/instanceof chain.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of going through all of these mental gymnastics, why not just write object oriented code, something like:

```
public abstract class AggDef { // horribly named class
    public abstract Type getType();
...
}
```

and override that method on each subclass.

```
public class StatAggDef extends AggDef { 

    @Override
    public Type getType() {
        //something concrete, ideally not a String....
    }

}
```

This is far more extensible when you add new types.  Using `instanceof` is a pretty good indication that you haven't really modeled your application correctly.

Comment: or even better, `interface Typed { Type getType(); }` and `class AggDef implements Typed ...`

Comment: This unfortunately is not an option as the AggDef that eventually becomes available contains a list of AggDefs. And if those aggDefs contain a specific type, the whole type would be differnet

Comment: @Horse I think you need to show that in your question then - please edit it to provide a bit more detail

Comment: Thats fine.  You can define a CompositeAggDef that contains many AggDefs, and encapsulate the behavior of the CompositeAggDef inside of getType()

Comment: But the AggDef is the one that contains the list of AggDefs.